# How to boot using the live USB with nVidia GTX 1060?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, live-usb

I have created a USB with Ubuntu 64bit 16.04.1 LTS. (This exact same issue also exists with Fedora 64bit 24-1.2) Initial text mode seems to work fine and I can see the various startup messages, however right about when the graphical interface should show up, my monitor reports that there's no longer a signal.

I have a nVidia GTX 1060, which is a fairly new card, about one month old.

I can see a `nouveau unknown chipset` error in the text mode status messages.

I have tried booting with:

- nouveau.modeset=0
- nomodeset
- nomodeset grub_gfxmode=1280x1024x24
- nomodeset rdblacklist=nouveau

None of these solve the problem. I still don't have any signal coming into my monitor when the graphical interface should show up.

What additional steps could I take in order to run a linux graphical interface from a USB with my existing hardware?

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu's Nouveau package is old enough to not have GeForce 10xx series support in it.  The latest Nouveau packages do, though.  Quick search gives me 2 options, both mutually exclusive - Nvidia's linux drivers (1) and building Nouveau from source (2). 

1 - http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/106780/en-us
2 - https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/InstallNouveau/#recompilation